# How to create a selectlist populated by records that list lookup relationship records?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, list, selectlist

I have been stuck on this problem for days. Basically I have a select list populated by all records in the custom object "Sprint__c". When I select a record in that select list, I am trying to list all the records in custom object "User_Story__c" where the lookup relationship field on the user story is the selected sprint in the select list.

So far, this is what I have gotten on the controller:

```
public class rw_userstorycontroller {

    public User_Story__c theStory {get;set;}
    public Sprint__c theSprint {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getStorysprints() {     
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<rw_sprint__c> Sprints =  [Select id, Name, timeframe__c,total_capacity__c From rw_sprint__c WHERE total_capacity__c !=0];
        options.add(new SelectOption('0001', '--Select--'));
        for(rw_sprint__c spr : Sprints ){
            options.add(new  SelectOption(spr.id, spr.timeframe__c));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public String selectedsprint {get; set;}

    public List<RW_User_story__c> getstorysprints1(){
        if(selectedValue == 'sprints'){  
            return [SELECT Id,Name,Status__c, CreatedDate FROM RW_User_story__c WHERE rw_userstory_sprints__c = :'sprints.id'];  
        } else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Visualforce contains something like this (where "sprints" is the ID of the part of the page that displays the list of RW_User_story__c objects and so needs to be re-rendered):

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedsprint}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!storysprints}"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="sprints"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

then these changes to the controller should make the logic work:

```
public Id selectedsprint {get; set;}

public List<RW_User_story__c> getstorysprints1(){
    if (selectedsprint != null){  
        return [
                SELECT Id,Name,Status__c, CreatedDate
                FROM RW_User_story__c
                WHERE rw_userstory_sprints__c = :selectedsprint
                ORDER BY Name
                ];  
    } else {
        return new List<RW_User_story__c>();
    }
}
```

See [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) for information about how to bind variables into SOQL queries.